# Connect to hidden wireless in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I'm trying out the developer preview for Touch, and unfortunately I don't have public WiFi I can connect to. Is there a way to add hidden networks? I can't find any kind of settings page or anything.

**EDIT**:

There may be a way to do this from the command line. I found that /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ stores a list of wifi connections that have been connected to. There may be a way to manually enter your hidden network here, though I haven't found anything yet.

Also, someone on IRC mentioned that the `phablet-network-setup` script can be used to copy network settings from your desktop to the "phablet." Unfortunately I didn't get either of these to fully work, so if someone has had better luck please feel free to post the answer here. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known issue](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes#Networking) of the current preview. There is no way for it right now but it might change soon.