# How do I connect to wireless network with hidden SSID on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch

I have created this question because of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259405/connect-to-hidden-wireless-in-ubuntu-touch) downvoted and closed one.

Come on... this is linux and everything is possible.

The current daily build of the **Ubuntu Touch** doesn't allow to connect to WiFi networks with hidden SSID through GUI.

How do I connect to hidden WiFi on the Ubuntu Touch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, connect your phablet to PC and copy over your connection info:

> # phablet-network -n
>   /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YourSSID.conf

or just create new .conf file on the phablet at `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YourSSID.conf`.

Start adbd as root

> # adb root

Enter shell

> # adb shell

Edit file (if you don't like vi, you can always use ed :), not sure if there is any other editor available. You could also edit this file directly on your PC)

> # vi
>   /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/active_ws_connection.conf

under `[802-11-wireless]` add:

> seen-bssids=00:00:00:00:00:00;

replace with MAC address of your AP.

Save file and `reboot` the phablet.